# angular routing when page is refreshed - child route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-material

When I refresh the page I want to stay on the current page but currently when I refresh it navigates to the other page.

Is this something to do with routes or state?.

When user click a row it triggeres editDeal and navigate to the deals/detail/ page. My issue right now is I want to stay on the current page which is the deals/detail/ when I hit refresh but currently the state is lost .

Someone said Child route with child route-outlet will do but it has no clatifications. Maybe someone has an idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

How do we do that in angular ? Thanks.

#code

```
  editDeal(deal:any){
    let dealType = '';
    const state = { 
      data: {
        transaction: this.transaction,
        dealId: deal.id,
        dealType: dealType,
        dealName: deal.name,
        deal: deal,
        hasPendingApproval: this.hasPendingAprroval,
      },      
    }
    this.gotoDealDetails(state);    
  }

  gotoDealDetails(state:any){
    this.route.navigateByUrl(`deals/detail/`, {state: state});
  }
```

#my ts route code

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DealDetailsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'detail/:data',  canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DealDetailsComponent, data: {
          userRoles: [Roles.ADMIN]
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class DealsModule { }
```

#main route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'deals',
        loadChildren: () => import('./features/deals/deals.module').then(m => m.DealsModule),
        data: {
          title: 'Deals',
          userRoles: [Roles.ADMIN]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if im getting you correctly.

So when you refresh the page(f5) you want to retain your state right?
The thing is that javascript actually looses all the data in a page refresh so you have to give it something to load it from.

I guess that you can fetch at somepoint from the backend your data

There are several ways to do this one way would be params so your app would get the necessary infos from the url.

would look something like this

"DealDetailsComponent"

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams) => {
  console.log(queryParams)
  loadDataFromBackend(queryParams.id)
 }
}
```

for this to work you would actually route like this

```
this.router.navigate(['deals/detail/'], {
  queryParams: { dealId: deal.id },
});
```

your end url in the browser would look like this domain.com/deals/detail?dealId=1

another way to persist the data could be the use of the localstorage and on component load you load the data from the local storage.

Comment: My current issue right now is when I refresh the deals/details page it redirects to other page which I dont understand why , is that something to do with the routes or states ?

Comment: that is my current issue

Comment: When I refresh the page I want to stay on the current page but currently when I refresh it navigates to the other page.

Comment: Change this in the ts route code 

  path: 'detail/:data'

to path:'detail'

Comment: I changed  path: 'detail/:data' to path:'detail' now it no longer redirect to the details page cause it can no longer recognized the url

Comment: when you refresh you want to stay on the deals/detail page?
Which page are you getting when you refresh at the moment?

Comment: yeah I want to stay on the deals/detail page regarding of the data state , when I refresh right now it goes to the index page. I think it has something to do with the child route